# Saving loop data in a text file in C#

Tags: c#, output

I want to save the out put of a loop after each iteration in a text file so that i can plot the data in a graph. I am giving the code in C#. any help in this regard will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    **
    if(rt>0)
      {
        t=t+delt1;
        float re=ve1*delt1+(0.5f*gt*Mathf.Pow(delt1,2));
        rt=rt-re;
        ve1=vg1+gt*delt1;
        gt=(G*M)/(rt*rt);
        print (" t  : "+t+" rt  : "+rt+" v :  "+vg1+" g : "+gt+" re  :  "+re);




        limit=true;

      }
     else
      {
            limit=false;
      }
```

**

Comment: where is your problem exactly? Does it compile? Does it crash? Is the output unexpected?

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\WriteLines.txt",true))
    {
     yourlooping ..
     {
             if(rt>0)
                 {
                   t=t+delt1;
                   float re=ve1*delt1+(0.5f*gt*Mathf.Pow(delt1,2));
                   rt=rt-re;
                   ve1=vg1+gt*delt1;
                   gt=(G*M)/(rt*rt);
                   file.WriteLine(t + " " + rt + " " + vg1 + " " + gt + " " + re);
                   limit=true;
                 }
              else
                 {
                  limit=false;
                 }

     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to write t, rt, vg1, gt, and re to the file.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("fileName.txt");
String toBeWritten = t + " " + rt + " " + vg1 + " " + gt + " " + re;
sw.writeLine(toBeWritten);
```

"fileName.txt" can be changed to whatever text file you want to write to.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> str = new List<String>();
str.Add("A");
str.Add("B");
str.Add("C");
str.Add("D");
str.Add("E");
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("PathOfFile"))
{
     foreach(string s in str)
     {
          // writer.Write(s); // Writes in same line
          writer.WriteLine(s);// Writes in next line
     }
}
```

The string A,B,C,D,E will be written in seperate lines after this loop.